# Anonymous Unions data member value conflicts

Tags: c++

I'm using anonymous union and tried for a simple program. but i found whatever i'm inputting in `Varname` variable the value is not being fetched. Please let me know where the gap is. Thanks in advance.  Here is a code of the program.

```
using namespace std;
int main(){
    union{
        char varName[100];
        char varContactNo[20];
    };
    cout << "Enter your name :";
    cin.getline(varName,100);
    //cin >> varName;
    cout << "\nEnter you contact no :";
    cin.getline(varContactNo,20);
    //cin >> varContactNo;
    cout << "\nPlease reach to Mr./Mrs. " << varName << " at "<< varContactNo;
    return 0;   
}
```

The output for the program is :

```
Enter your name :Rajan Kashyap

Enter you contact no : XXX

Please reach to Mr./Mrs. XXX at XXX
```

If I comment the union line and make it a simple program then it works.

```
//union{
        char varName[100];
        char varContactNo[20];
//  };
```

Comment: That's just not how `union` works. You probably wanted to use `struct`.

Comment: You misunderstood what a [union](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union) is: "*a union is a special class type that can hold* ***only one of*** *its non-static data members at a time*".

Comment: `union` is for specifying a common memory location for all members of that union. For your case, it will actually cause *Undefined Behavior* because `varContactNumber` will overwrite `varName` and from the output, you can see they hold the same value. Also, is there any specific reason *why* you wanted to use a `union` here?

Comment: Okey I got it. Actually I was getting in touch with the concept of ```Anonymous Unions``` in which secenerio I had to use union. The concept union itself state my answer.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `union` can contain only one of it's members at any time. It's only legal to read the member that was last written. You probably wanted to use `struct`. Note that C++ does not allow anonymus structs, so you need to give it a name:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    struct {
        char varName[100];
        char varContactNo[20];
    } data;
    cout << "Enter your name :";
    cin.getline(data.varName,100);
    //cin >> varName;
    cout << "\nEnter you contact no :";
    cin.getline(data.varContactNo,20);
    //cin >> varContactNo;
    cout << "\nPlease reach to Mr./Mrs. " << data.varName << " at "<< data.varContactNo;
    return 0;   
}
```